# Grails plugins not downloading from Eclipse - Luna

Tags: eclipse, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am just setting up my Grails/Groovy STS suite in Eclipse. I created a new Grails Project, and when I right click on the project and select *Grails* -> *Refresh Dependencies*, it is failing to download dependencies (error log below) and hence doesn't build my project.

I think it could be a proxy issue, but I never had a proxy setup in my Eclipse and I always download Spring suites/and all other plugins from update sites or Market place just fine, so can't be a proxy issue.

In addition, I did not check all the urls, but some urls printed to the console are in fact throwing 404 error! It is the latest installation of STS, and how come it is looking at the wrong locations? Do I need to do anything?

Any thoughts?

(first few lines of error messages from console)

```
Starting process on MYPC/XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
Loading Grails 2.4.3
|Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    Host repo.grails.org not found. url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.pom
    Host repo.grails.org not found. url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.zip
    Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.pom
    Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.zip
    Host snapshots.repository.codehaus.org not found. url=http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.pom
    Host snapshots.repository.codehaus.org not found. url=http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.zip
    Host repository.codehaus.org not found. url=http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.pom
    Host repository.codehaus.org not found. url=http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.zip
    Host download.java.net not found. url=http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.pom
    Host download.java.net not found. url=http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.zip
    Host repository.jboss.com not found. url=http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.pom
    Host repository.jboss.com not found. url=http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.zip
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.4.3
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.4.3!tomcat.zip:
      Y:\workspaces_trunk\GMon\lib\tomcat-2.4.3.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Programs\eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\grails-2.4.3\lib\org.grails.plugins\tomcat\ivy-2.4.3.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.4.3!tomcat.zip:
      C:\Programs\eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\grails-2.4.3\lib\org.grails.plugins\tomcat\jars\tomcat-2.4.3.zip
      C:\Programs\eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\grails-2.4.3\lib\org.grails.plugins\tomcat\bundles\tomcat-2.4.3.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Programs\eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\grails-2.4.3\dist\tomcat-2.4.3.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.4.3!tomcat.zip:
      C:\Programs\eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\grails-2.4.3\dist\tomcat-2.4.3.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Users\rp48085\.grails\2.4.3\cached-installed-plugins\tomcat-2.4.3.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.4.3!tomcat.zip:
      C:\Users\rp48085\.grails\2.4.3\cached-installed-plugins\tomcat-2.4.3.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      C:\Programs\eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\grails-2.4.3\plugins\tomcat-2.4.3.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.4.3!tomcat.zip:
      C:\Programs\eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\grails-2.4.3\plugins\tomcat-2.4.3.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.pom
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;2.4.3!tomcat.zip:
```

Comment: It's running now - could you try again? If it still doesn't work, can you open one of the repo.grails.org urls in a web browser?

Comment: In fact, this URL http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/2.4.3/tomcat-2.4.3.pom, returns error. So it seems that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: no luck, i tried running grails add-proxy and grails set-proxy commands, but it still doesn't download.

Comment: Ok @BurtBeckwith I tried setting the proxy without http:// in the front, now host not found errors are gone!! but it is not able to dowload tomcat and hibernate! 
</br>
org.grails.plugins#hibernate;2.4.3: not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by running "grails add-proxy" and "grails set-proxy" commands one after the other. I have tried setting the proxy settings in Eclipse->Window->Preferences, as thats how I have always done to get plugins/downloads going from Eclipse. But grails apparently doesn't use these settings, so it needs to be given proxy settings using the above commands.

Comment: could you elaborate what exactly the proxy should be?